# What happened to Charles Xavier's money?

Tags: logan

Now we may not know what happened to his money but it seems funny to me that Charles Xavier is living with Logan almost a complete reversal of roles in X men.

What happened to Charles Xavier's money?  If we don't know is there any reference to this in the movie that might lead us to guess?  From some quick searching it appears this doesn't follow the comic books as much so to speak as some other movies.

Comment: The movie made it pretty clear that *Knivre pbzzvggrq znff zheqre va gur "Jrfgpurfgre rirag"*.  Besides the expected criminal complaints, there would be many *jebatshy qrngu* civil suits given Xavier's wealth.  Since Xavier went on the lam, he'd have missed court dates, which would have produced default judgments, which in turn would have gotten his bank accounts frozen.

Comment: @KyleJones is that an exact quote.  Just kidding. I have only see the movie once and don't remember this.  Will have to re watch.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

During the film *Logan* Charles, who is suffering from a degenerative brain disease of some kind, is on the run and being protected by Logan after

> accidentally killing several people, implied to be the rest of the xmen, as a seizure caused him to inflict a psychic attack. Logan is better able to resist this effect, presumably due to his healing factor.

Under these circumstances, there is no way for Charles to access his money. Upon making himself known, he would either be arrested or killed on sight by government agents.

Comment: So would she be thankful he didn't kill anyone in vegas

Comment: @William They didn't go to Vegas, they were in Oklahoma City.

Answer (score 0):

The Marvel story line in regards to Charles money in Logan.  I believe it was stolen by criminals that hunt these mutants. Striker was one who stole alot, whenever striker attacked a mutant headquarter he raided everything. One of the movies he is seen blowing up the mansion and his team took a couple meetings plus they took whatever they thought they needed which included a lot of high-tech gear. However one theory is Charles hid his money and during his mind breaking he forgot where it was at. There was small discussion about the whereabouts of the money. Hints and clues, but Professor still has his wealth

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).